# When securing MySql, is it better to create a user with root-like priviliges and then remove the 'root' user?

Tags: mysql

This would seems to prevent attackers who know that a 'root' user exists?

Comment: Exactly would you imagine to gain from that, in relation to having a solid root password?

Comment: Because having to guess a username and password is twice as hard at just guessing the password?

Comment: No, because the username isn't meant to be a secret, hence the system will put much less efforts into hiding/protecting it. If you want to increase the amounts of possible combination  you will get a much better effect by simply making your password longer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't remove the MySQL 'root' user, just rename it instead:

```
mysql> update user set user="somecrazyname" where user="root";
mysql> flush privileges;
```

I can't rightly imagine what will happen if you go deleting the root user.

Comment: It wouldn't make any difference for MySQL if you removed the initial 'root' user but you wouldn't be able to create any more databases/tables etc. if your other users don't have the right privileges.

Comment: Just a note here, the database must be specified so you would have `mysql> update mysql.user set user=...etc`